# Is there a Preview Handler VCL for Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, windows-7

This article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb776867.aspx

describes preview handlers in Windows as

> Preview handlers are called when an
>   item is selected to show a
>   lightweight, rich, read-only preview
>   of the file's contents in the view's
>   reading pane. This is done without
>   launching the file's associated
>   application.

and ...

> A preview handler is a hosted
>   application. Hosts include the
>   Microsoft Windows Explorer in Windows
>   Vista or Microsoft Outlook 2007.

Is there some Delphi VCL code which can be used as a startingpoint for such a handler?

Comment: I presume you are aware that, until the Delphi 64 bit version is released, then Delphi cannot produce a preview handler for 64 bit Windows.

Comment: @David Heffernan 64 Bit Windows and 64 bit Outlook can host 32 bit preview handlers using the DllSurrogate technique.

Comment: @Jamie OK, I hadn't realised that preview handlers are out-of-proc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Mjn, right know I'm writing an article for my [blog](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/) to implement Preview Handlers from Delphi, but due to lack of time, I do not know when this is complete, as others users mention by the moment no exist a VCL component in Delphi to implement preview handlers, in the past I implemented a couple of preview handlers for a customer but using Delphi-Prism and C#.

As starting point here I leave some tips.

- You must use the [`IPreviewHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), InitializeWithFile, [`InitializeWithStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`IPreviewHandlerFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), IPreviewHandlerVisuals interfaces.

This is the Delphi translation of the headers of these interfaces

```
uses
  Windows, ActiveX, AxCtrls, ShlObj, ComObj;

type


  IIPreviewHandler = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}']
    function SetWindow(hwnd: HWND; var RectangleRef: TRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetRect(var RectangleRef: TRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DoPreview(): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Unload(): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetFocus(): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function QueryFocus(phwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function TranslateAccelerator(PointerToWindowMessage: MSG): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  IInitializeWithFile = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{b7d14566-0509-4cce-a71f-0a554233bd9b}']
    function Initialize(pszFilePath: LPWSTR; grfMode: DWORD):HRESULT;stdcall;
  end;

  IInitializeWithStream = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{b824b49d-22ac-4161-ac8a-9916e8fa3f7f}']
    function Initialize(pstream: IStream; grfMode: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  IIPreviewHandlerFrame = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{fec87aaf-35f9-447a-adb7-20234491401a}']
    function GetWindowContext(pinfo: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function TranslateAccelerator(PointerToWindowMessage: MSG): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  IIPreviewHandlerVisuals = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{8327b13c-b63f-4b24-9b8a-d010dcc3f599}']
        function SetBackgroundColor(color: COLORREF ): HRESULT; stdcall;
        function SetFont(plf:LOGFONTW): HRESULT; stdcall;  
        function SetTextColor(color: COLORREF): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
```

- You must create a com dll with a class which descend from these interfaces IIPreviewHandler, IIPreviewHandlerVisuals, IOleWindow, IObjectWithSite to manage the visualization and a second class to load the files to show. this class must descend from `IPreviewHandler`, `IInitializeWithStream`.

something like this

```
  TMyPreviewHandler = class(IIPreviewHandler, IIPreviewHandlerVisuals, IOleWindow, IObjectWithSite)

  TMyStream = class(IIPreviewHandler, IInitializeWithStream, IStream)
```

- Now you must create your own implementation of the methods for the parent interfaces.
  this is the list of the methods which you need implement.

  **IPreviewHandler** ->  DoPreview, SetWindow, SetRect, Unload, SetFocus, TranslateAccelerator, QueryFocus.

  **IObjectWithSite** -> GetSite, SetSite.

  **IOleWindow**      -> GetWindow

  **IPreviewHandlerVisuals** - > SetBackgroundColor, SetFont, SetColor

  **InitializeWithStream** -> Initialize
- finally you must register your COM in the system as well as the file extensions which will use you PrevieHandler class.
- Check this project as a starting point [`Windows Preview Handler Pack`](http://previewhandlers.codeplex.com/) (is written in C#) and this article [`View Data Your Way With Our Managed Preview Handler Framework`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163487.aspx)

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for your blog post.  This is of much interest to me.

Answer (score 6):

I have made this unit to handle all the preview handler stuff:

```
unit PreviewHandler;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{.$DEFINE USE_CODESITE}

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, ComObj;

type
  TPreviewHandler = class abstract
  public
    { Create all controls needed for the preview and connect them to the
      parent given. The parent follows the size, color and font of the preview
      pane. The parent will stay valid until this instance is destroyed, so if
      you make the parent also the owner of the controls you don't need to free
      them in Destroy. }
    constructor Create(AParent: TWinControl); virtual;
    class function GetComClass: TComClass; virtual; abstract;
    class procedure Register(const AClassID: TGUID; const AName, ADescription, AFileExtension: string);
    {$REGION 'Clear Content'}
    /// <summary>Clear Content</summary>
    /// <remarks>This method is called when the preview should be cleared because
    /// either another item was selected or the PreviewHandler will be
    /// closed.</remarks>
    {$ENDREGION}
    procedure Unload; virtual;
  end;

  TStreamPreviewHandler = class abstract(TPreviewHandler)
  public
    {$REGION 'Render the preview from the stream data'}
    /// <summary>Render the preview from the stream data</summary>
    /// <remarks>Here you should render the data from the stream in whatever
    /// fashion you want.</remarks>
    {$ENDREGION}
    procedure DoPreview(Stream: TStream); virtual; abstract;
    class function GetComClass: TComClass; override; final;
  end;

  TFilePreviewHandler = class abstract(TPreviewHandler)
  public
    {$REGION 'Render the preview from the file path'}
    /// <summary>Render the preview from the file path</summary>
    /// <remarks>Here you should render the data from the file path in whatever
    /// fashion you want.</remarks>
    {$ENDREGION}
    procedure DoPreview(const FilePath: String); virtual; abstract;
    class function GetComClass: TComClass; override; final;
  end;

implementation

uses
{$IFDEF USE_CODESITE}
  CodeSiteLogging,
{$ENDIF}
  Windows, ActiveX, ComServ, ShlObj, PropSys, Types, SysUtils, Graphics, ExtCtrls;

type
  TPreviewHandlerClass = class of TPreviewHandler;
  TComPreviewHandler = class(TComObject, IPreviewHandler, IPreviewHandlerVisuals, IObjectWithSite, IOleWindow)
  strict private
    function IPreviewHandler.DoPreview = IPreviewHandler_DoPreview;
    function ContextSensitiveHelp(fEnterMode: LongBool): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetSite(const riid: TGUID; out site: IInterface): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetWindow(out wnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function IPreviewHandler_DoPreview: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function QueryFocus(var phwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetBackgroundColor(color: Cardinal): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetFocus: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetFont(const plf: tagLOGFONTW): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetRect(var prc: TRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetSite(const pUnkSite: IInterface): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetTextColor(color: Cardinal): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetWindow(hwnd: HWND; var prc: TRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function TranslateAccelerator(var pmsg: tagMSG): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Unload: HRESULT; stdcall;
  private
    FBackgroundColor: Cardinal;
    FBounds: TRect;
    FContainer: TWinControl;
    FLogFont: tagLOGFONTW;
    FParentWindow: HWND;
    FPreviewHandler: TPreviewHandler;
    FPreviewHandlerClass: TPreviewHandlerClass;
    FPreviewHandlerFrame: IPreviewHandlerFrame;
    FSite: IInterface;
    FTextColor: Cardinal;
  protected
    procedure CheckContainer;
    procedure CheckPreviewHandler;
    procedure InternalUnload; virtual; abstract;
    procedure InternalDoPreview; virtual; abstract;
    property Container: TWinControl read FContainer;
    property PreviewHandler: TPreviewHandler read FPreviewHandler;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property PreviewHandlerClass: TPreviewHandlerClass read FPreviewHandlerClass write FPreviewHandlerClass;
  end;

  TComStreamPreviewHandler = class(TComPreviewHandler, IInitializeWithStream)
  strict private
    function IInitializeWithStream.Initialize = IInitializeWithStream_Initialize;
    function IInitializeWithStream_Initialize(const pstream: IStream; grfMode: Cardinal): HRESULT; stdcall;
  private
    FIStream: IStream;
    FMode: Cardinal;
    function GetPreviewHandler: TStreamPreviewHandler;
  protected
    procedure InternalUnload; override;
    procedure InternalDoPreview; override;
    property PreviewHandler: TStreamPreviewHandler read GetPreviewHandler;
  end;

  TComFilePreviewHandler = class(TComPreviewHandler, IInitializeWithFile)
  strict private
    function IInitializeWithFile.Initialize = IInitializeWithFile_Initialize;
    function IInitializeWithFile_Initialize(pszFilePath: LPCWSTR; grfMode: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
  private
    FFilePath: string;
    FMode: DWORD;
    function GetPreviewHandler: TFilePreviewHandler;
  protected
    procedure InternalDoPreview; override;
    procedure InternalUnload; override;
    property PreviewHandler: TFilePreviewHandler read GetPreviewHandler;
  end;

  TComPreviewHandlerFactory = class(TComObjectFactory)
  private
    FFileExtension: string;
    FPreviewHandlerClass: TPreviewHandlerClass;
    class procedure DeleteRegValue(const Key, ValueName: string; RootKey: DWord);
    class function IsRunningOnWOW64: Boolean;
  protected
    property FileExtension: string read FFileExtension;
  public
    constructor Create(APreviewHandlerClass: TPreviewHandlerClass; const AClassID: TGUID; const AName, ADescription, AFileExtension: string);
    function CreateComObject(const Controller: IUnknown): TComObject; override;
    procedure UpdateRegistry(Register: Boolean); override;
    property PreviewHandlerClass: TPreviewHandlerClass read FPreviewHandlerClass;
  end;

  TWinControlHelper = class helper for TWinControl
  public
    procedure SetFocusTabFirst;
    procedure SetFocusTabLast;
    procedure SetBackgroundColor(AColor: Cardinal);
    procedure SetBoundsRect(const ARect: TRect);
    procedure SetTextColor(AColor: Cardinal);
    procedure SetTextFont(const Source: tagLOGFONTW);
  end;

  TIStreamAdapter = class(TStream)
  private
    FTarget: IStream;
  protected
    function GetSize: Int64; override;
    procedure SetSize(NewSize: Longint); override;
    procedure SetSize(const NewSize: Int64); override;
  public
    constructor Create(ATarget: IStream);
    function Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; override;
    function Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: TSeekOrigin): Int64; overload; override;
    function Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; override;
    property Target: IStream read FTarget;
  end;

procedure TWinControlHelper.SetFocusTabFirst;
begin
  SelectNext(nil, true, true);
end;

procedure TWinControlHelper.SetFocusTabLast;
begin
  SelectNext(nil, false, true);
end;

procedure TWinControlHelper.SetBackgroundColor(AColor: Cardinal);
begin
  Color := AColor;
end;

procedure TWinControlHelper.SetBoundsRect(const ARect: TRect);
begin
  SetBounds(ARect.Left, ARect.Top, ARect.Right - ARect.Left, ARect.Bottom - ARect.Top);
end;

procedure TWinControlHelper.SetTextColor(AColor: Cardinal);
begin
  Font.Color := AColor;
end;

procedure TWinControlHelper.SetTextFont(const Source: tagLOGFONTW);
var
  fontStyle: TFontStyles;
begin
  Font.Height := Source.lfHeight;
  fontStyle := Font.Style;
  if Source.lfWeight >= FW_BOLD then
    Include(fontStyle, fsBold);
  if Source.lfItalic = 1 then
    Include(fontStyle, fsItalic);
  if Source.lfUnderline = 1 then
    Include(fontStyle, fsUnderline);
  if Source.lfStrikeOut = 1 then
    Include(fontStyle, fsStrikeOut);
  Font.Style := fontStyle;
  Font.Charset := TFontCharset(Source.lfCharSet);
  Font.Name := Source.lfFaceName;
  case Source.lfPitchAndFamily and $F of
    VARIABLE_PITCH: Font.Pitch := fpVariable;
    FIXED_PITCH: Font.Pitch := fpFixed;
  else
    Font.Pitch := fpDefault;
  end;
  Font.Orientation := Source.lfOrientation;
end;

constructor TComPreviewHandlerFactory.Create(APreviewHandlerClass: TPreviewHandlerClass; const AClassID: TGUID; const
    AName, ADescription, AFileExtension: string);
begin
  inherited Create(ComServ.ComServer, APreviewHandlerClass.GetComClass, AClassID, AName, ADescription, ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
  FPreviewHandlerClass := APreviewHandlerClass;
  FFileExtension := AFileExtension;
end;

function TComPreviewHandlerFactory.CreateComObject(const Controller: IUnknown): TComObject;
begin
  result := inherited CreateComObject(Controller);
  TComPreviewHandler(result).PreviewHandlerClass := PreviewHandlerClass;
end;

class procedure TComPreviewHandlerFactory.DeleteRegValue(const Key, ValueName: string; RootKey: DWord);
var
  RegKey: HKEY;
begin
  if RegOpenKeyEx(RootKey, PChar(Key), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, regKey) = ERROR_SUCCESS then begin
    try
      RegDeleteValue(regKey, PChar(ValueName));
    finally
      RegCloseKey(regKey)
    end;
  end;
end;

class function TComPreviewHandlerFactory.IsRunningOnWOW64: Boolean;
{ code taken from www.delphidabbler.com "IsWow64" }
type
  // Type of IsWow64Process API fn
  TIsWow64Process = function(Handle: Windows.THandle; var Res: Windows.BOOL): Windows.BOOL; stdcall;
var
  IsWow64Result: Windows.BOOL; // Result from IsWow64Process
  IsWow64Process: TIsWow64Process; // IsWow64Process fn reference
begin
{$IF defined(CPUX64)}
  // compiled for 64-bit: can't be running on Wow64
  result := false;
{$ELSE}
  // Try to load required function from kernel32
  IsWow64Process := Windows.GetProcAddress(Windows.GetModuleHandle('kernel32'), 'IsWow64Process');
  if Assigned(IsWow64Process) then begin
    // Function is implemented: call it
    if not IsWow64Process(Windows.GetCurrentProcess, IsWow64Result) then
      raise SysUtils.Exception.Create('IsWindows64: bad process handle');
    // Return result of function
    Result := IsWow64Result;
  end
  else
    // Function not implemented: can't be running on Wow64
    Result := False;
{$IFEND}
end;

procedure TComPreviewHandlerFactory.UpdateRegistry(Register: Boolean);
var
  plainFileName: string;
  sAppID, sClassID, ProgID, ServerKeyName, RegPrefix: string;
  RootKey: HKEY;
  RootKey2: HKEY;
begin
  if Instancing = ciInternal then
    Exit;

  ComServer.GetRegRootAndPrefix(RootKey, RegPrefix);
  if ComServer.PerUserRegistration then
    RootKey2 := HKEY_CURRENT_USER
  else
    RootKey2 := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  sClassID := GUIDToString(ClassID);
  ProgID := GetProgID;
  ServerKeyName := RegPrefix + 'CLSID\' + sClassID + '\' + ComServer.ServerKey;
  if IsRunningOnWOW64 then
    sAppID := '{534A1E02-D58F-44f0-B58B-36CBED287C7C}' // for Win32 shell extension running on Win64
  else
    sAppID := '{6d2b5079-2f0b-48dd-ab7f-97cec514d30b}';

  if Register then begin
    inherited;
    plainFileName := ExtractFileName(ComServer.ServerFileName);
    CreateRegKey(RegPrefix + 'CLSID\' + sClassID, 'AppID', sAppID, RootKey);
    if ProgID <> '' then begin
      CreateRegKey(ServerKeyName, 'ProgID', ProgID, RootKey);
      CreateRegKey(ServerKeyName, 'VersionIndependentProgID', ProgID, RootKey);
      CreateRegKey(RegPrefix + ProgID + '\shellex\' + SID_IPreviewHandler, '', sClassID, RootKey);
      CreateRegKey(RegPrefix + FileExtension, '', ProgID, RootKey);
      CreateRegKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers', sClassID, Description, RootKey2);
    end;
  end
  else begin
    if ProgID <> '' then begin
      DeleteRegValue('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers', sClassID, RootKey2);
      DeleteRegKey(RegPrefix + FileExtension, RootKey);
      DeleteRegKey(RegPrefix + ProgID + '\shellex', RootKey);
    end;
    inherited;
  end;
end;

destructor TComPreviewHandler.Destroy;
begin
  FPreviewHandler.Free;
  FContainer.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TComPreviewHandler.CheckContainer;
begin
  if FContainer = nil then begin
    { I sprang for a TPanel here, because it makes things so much simpler. }
    FContainer := TPanel.Create(nil);
    TPanel(FContainer).BevelOuter := bvNone;
    FContainer.SetBackgroundColor(FBackgroundColor);
    FContainer.SetTextFont(FLogFont);
    FContainer.SetTextColor(FTextColor);
    FContainer.SetBoundsRect(FBounds);
    FContainer.ParentWindow := FParentWindow;
  end;
end;

procedure TComPreviewHandler.CheckPreviewHandler;
begin
  if FPreviewHandler = nil then begin
    CheckContainer;
    FPreviewHandler := PreviewHandlerClass.Create(Container);
  end;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.ContextSensitiveHelp(fEnterMode: LongBool): HRESULT;
begin
  result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.GetSite(const riid: TGUID; out site: IInterface): HRESULT;
begin
  site := nil;
  if FSite = nil then
    result := E_FAIL
  else if Supports(FSite, riid, site) then
    result := S_OK
  else
    result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.GetWindow(out wnd: HWND): HRESULT;
begin
  if Container = nil then begin
    result := E_FAIL;
  end
  else begin
    wnd := Container.Handle;
    result := S_OK;
  end;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.IPreviewHandler_DoPreview: HRESULT;
begin
  try
    CheckPreviewHandler;
    InternalDoPreview;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
    {$IFDEF USE_CODESITE}
      CodeSite.SendException(E);
    {$ENDIF}
    end;
  end;
  result := S_OK;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.QueryFocus(var phwnd: HWND): HRESULT;
begin
  phwnd := GetFocus;
  result := S_OK;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.SetBackgroundColor(color: Cardinal): HRESULT;
begin
  FBackgroundColor := color;
  if Container <> nil then
    Container.SetBackgroundColor(FBackgroundColor);
  result := S_OK;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.SetFocus: HRESULT;
begin
  if Container <> nil then begin
    if GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0 then
      Container.SetFocusTabLast
    else
      Container.SetFocusTabFirst;
  end;
  result := S_OK;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.SetFont(const plf: tagLOGFONTW): HRESULT;
begin
  FLogFont := plf;
  if Container <> nil then
    Container.SetTextFont(FLogFont);
  result := S_OK;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.SetRect(var prc: TRect): HRESULT;
begin
  FBounds := prc;
  if Container <> nil then
    Container.SetBoundsRect(FBounds);
  result := S_OK;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.SetSite(const pUnkSite: IInterface): HRESULT;
begin
  FSite := PUnkSite;
  FPreviewHandlerFrame := FSite as IPreviewHandlerFrame;
  result := S_OK;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.SetTextColor(color: Cardinal): HRESULT;
begin
  FTextColor := color;
  if Container <> nil then
    Container.SetTextColor(FTextColor);
  result := S_OK;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.SetWindow(hwnd: HWND; var prc: TRect): HRESULT;
begin
  FParentWindow := hwnd;
  FBounds := prc;
  if Container <> nil then begin
    Container.ParentWindow := FParentWindow;
    Container.SetBoundsRect(FBounds);
  end;
  result := S_OK;
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.TranslateAccelerator(var pmsg: tagMSG): HRESULT;
begin
  if FPreviewHandlerFrame = nil then
    result := S_FALSE
  else
    result := FPreviewHandlerFrame.TranslateAccelerator(pmsg);
end;

function TComPreviewHandler.Unload: HRESULT;
begin
  if PreviewHandler <> nil then
    PreviewHandler.Unload;
  InternalUnload;
  result := S_OK;
end;

constructor TPreviewHandler.Create(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited Create;
end;

class procedure TPreviewHandler.Register(const AClassID: TGUID; const AName, ADescription, AFileExtension: string);
begin
  TComPreviewHandlerFactory.Create(Self, AClassID, AName, ADescription, AFileExtension);
end;

procedure TPreviewHandler.Unload;
begin
end;

constructor TIStreamAdapter.Create(ATarget: IStream);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FTarget := ATarget;
end;

function TIStreamAdapter.GetSize: Int64;
var
  statStg: TStatStg;
begin
  if Target.Stat(statStg, STATFLAG_NONAME) = S_OK then
    result := statStg.cbSize
  else
    result := -1;
end;

function TIStreamAdapter.Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  Target.Read(@Buffer, Count, @result);
end;

function TIStreamAdapter.Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: TSeekOrigin): Int64;
begin
  Target.Seek(Offset, Ord(Origin), result);
end;

procedure TIStreamAdapter.SetSize(const NewSize: Int64);
begin
  raise ENotImplemented.Create('SetSize not implemented');
//  Target.SetSize(NewSize);
end;

procedure TIStreamAdapter.SetSize(NewSize: Longint);
begin
  SetSize(Int64(NewSize));
end;

function TIStreamAdapter.Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  raise ENotImplemented.Create('Write not implemented');
//  Target.Write(@Buffer, Count, @result);
end;

function TComStreamPreviewHandler.GetPreviewHandler: TStreamPreviewHandler;
begin
  Result := inherited PreviewHandler as TStreamPreviewHandler;
end;

function TComStreamPreviewHandler.IInitializeWithStream_Initialize(const pstream: IStream; grfMode: Cardinal): HRESULT;
begin
  FIStream := pStream;
  FMode := grfMode;
  result := S_OK;
end;

procedure TComStreamPreviewHandler.InternalUnload;
begin
  FIStream := nil;
end;

procedure TComStreamPreviewHandler.InternalDoPreview;
var
  stream: TIStreamAdapter;
begin
  stream := TIStreamAdapter.Create(FIStream);
  try
    PreviewHandler.DoPreview(stream);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;

function TComFilePreviewHandler.GetPreviewHandler: TFilePreviewHandler;
begin
  Result := inherited PreviewHandler as TFilePreviewHandler;
end;

function TComFilePreviewHandler.IInitializeWithFile_Initialize(pszFilePath: LPCWSTR; grfMode: DWORD): HRESULT;
begin
  FFilePath := pszFilePath;
  FMode := grfMode;
  result := S_OK;
end;

procedure TComFilePreviewHandler.InternalDoPreview;
begin
  PreviewHandler.DoPreview(FFilePath);
end;

procedure TComFilePreviewHandler.InternalUnload;
begin
  FFilePath := '';
end;

class function TFilePreviewHandler.GetComClass: TComClass;
begin
  result := TComFilePreviewHandler;
end;

class function TStreamPreviewHandler.GetComClass: TComClass;
begin
  result := TComStreamPreviewHandler;
end;

initialization
{$IFDEF USE_CODESITE}
  CodeSiteManager.ConnectUsingTcp;
{$ENDIF}
end.
```

A sample preview handler based on this unit is shown here:

```
unit MyPreviewHandler;

interface

uses
  PreviewHandler, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls;

const
  {$REGION 'Unique ClassID of your PreviewHandler'}
  ///   <summary>Unique ClassID of your PreviewHandler</summary>
  ///   <remarks>Don't forget to create a new one. Best use Ctrl-G.</remarks>
  {$ENDREGION}
  CLASS_MyPreviewHandler: TGUID = '{64644512-C345-469F-B5FB-EB351E20129D}';

type
  {$REGION 'Sample PreviewHandler'}
  ///   <summary>Sample PreviewHandler</summary>
  ///   <remarks>A sample PreviewHandler. You only have to derive from
  ///   TFilePreviewHandler or TStreamPreviewHandler and override some methods.</remarks>
  {$ENDREGION}
  TMyPreviewHandler = class(TFilePreviewHandler)
  private
    FTextLabel: TLabel;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AParent: TWinControl); override;
    procedure Unload; override;
    procedure DoPreview(const FilePath: string); override;
    property TextLabel: TLabel read FTextLabel;
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

constructor TMyPreviewHandler.Create(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited;
  FTextLabel := TLabel.Create(AParent);
  FTextLabel.Parent := AParent;
  FTextLabel.AutoSize := false;
  FTextLabel.Align := alClient;
  FTextLabel.Alignment := taCenter;
  FTextLabel.Layout := tlCenter;
  FTextLabel.WordWrap := true;
end;

procedure TMyPreviewHandler.DoPreview(const FilePath: string);
begin
  TextLabel.Caption := GetPackageDescription(PWideChar(FilePath));
end;

procedure TMyPreviewHandler.Unload;
begin
  TextLabel.Caption := '';
  inherited;
end;

initialization
  { Register your PreviewHandler with the ClassID, name, descripton and file extension }
  TMyPreviewHandler.Register(CLASS_MyPreviewHandler, 'bplfile', 'BPL Binary Preview Handler', '.bpl');
end.

library MyPreviewHandlerLib;

uses
  ComServ,
  PreviewHandler in 'PreviewHandler.pas' {PreviewHandler: CoClass},
  MyPreviewHandler in 'MyPreviewHandler.pas';

exports
  DllGetClassObject,
  DllCanUnloadNow,
  DllRegisterServer,
  DllUnregisterServer,
  DllInstall;

{$R *.RES}

begin
end.
```

You may be interested in [this article in my blog](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2011/06/01/windows-7-previews-the-delphi-way/) describing some more details on that framework.

Comment: Can you post a summary here instead of just a link to your blog?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard, sorry if i Missed it, but I thought I did exactly that. There might be more wordy ways to make it clear, but it actually is "describing a framework to implement your own preview handler". After all, it looks like a direct answer to the title question.

Comment: Your answer only describes what's behind the link, it doesn't really answer the question.  Rule of thumb: if that site goes down, will your post still answer the question?  Also, please mention that it's your blog whenever you link to it, as per the promotion policy in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).  See the accepted answer for an example.

Comment: Point taken - didn't look at it that way. I plan to upload the code to CodeCentral and change the link when done, if that is OK. Don't know how long CodeCentral will be around, though. Or is there another way to post some code here that is more than a few lines? I really didn't want to merely copy the article here, should I?

Comment: You don't have to reproduce the whole thing verbatim here, but just a summary plus your link would be good.  The code from your post is definitely not too long, but much longer code blocks will be displayed with a scroll bar so they don't steal the whole page.

Comment: Hi Uwe, Thanks for the great code. I have a question if you may. I'm trying to create a preview handler to display `SVG` graphic files. My code returns a simple BMP/PNG. should I use a container with a `TImage`? or do I need to return only some sort of stream without using a container (like your example does)? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen such a thing, but since the whole thing is build in COM, you would start by importing the type library, and implementing the required interfaces, including IPreviewHandlerFrame.  [Sorry, not very helpful.  But this is a pretty obscure area, so I'm not surprised that Delphi hasn't got a prebuilt component set for this.]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write a COM-Server yourself, which provides the described IPreviwHandler-Interfacees. (There is no type library to import...) I am very interested in such a code as well and I am searching for quite a while now. I am not very experienced with COM-Server-writing... If you find something, let me know please! As I will share my code also, if I get some...

Andreas

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is rather uncommon to include contact information in your posts (actually, you never do that). Instead, feel free to include all such information in your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/645044/andreas).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any references to using IPreviewHandlerFrame in Delphi, but did manage to come up with a C# example [here](http://files.codes-sources.com/fichier_fullscreen.aspx?id=50647&f=PreviewHandler%2FPreviewHandler%2FPreviewHandler.cs&lang=en) - maybe it'll give you a starting point.